# c# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, infopath

error in Infopath:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at InfoPathFormTemplate5.FormCode.CTRL407_5_Clicked(Object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
>      at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Internal.ButtonEventHost.OnButtonClick(DocActionEvent pEvent)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.SemiTrust._ButtonEventSink_SinkHelper.OnClick(DocActionEvent pEvent)
>
> error in VB2005: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>     Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>     Source="InfoPathFormTemplate5"
>     StackTrace:
>          at InfoPathFormTemplate5.FormCode.CTRL407_5_Clicked(Object sender, ClickedEventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\pebabczu\Desktop\IntakeForm Copy\InfoPathFormTemplate5\FormCode.cs:line 206
>          at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Internal.ButtonEventHost.OnButtonClick(DocActionEvent pEvent)
>          at Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.SemiTrust._ButtonEventSink_SinkHelper.OnClick(DocActionEvent pEvent)

Code:

```
string TeamL = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:field149", ns).Value;
string ACC = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Bank", ns).Value;
string remarkmain = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:field104", ns).Value;
string RemarkHR = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Remarks1", ns).Value;
string RemarkTL = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:field55", ns).Value;
string RemarkIT = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:RemarksICT", ns).Value;
string Rmain = "Remarks: " + remarkmain;
string RHR = "Remarks: " + RemarkHR;
string RTL = "Remarks: " + RemarkTL;
string RIT = "Remarks: " + RemarkIT;
```

I dont get it... Just getting into C# what did I do wrong.?

Comment: string RemarkIT = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:RemarksICT", ns).Value;

Comment: definitely the one returning the null dont know why though...checke all  the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're dereferencing something that turns out to be null.

It's hard to say exactly which line of code is problematic out of what you posted, but you should look at line 206. I strongly suspect that `SelectSingleNode` is returning `null` for one of your XPath expressions - you're then trying to access the `Value` property, which is causing the exception.

So, you need to:

- Work out which line is causing the problem
- Find out whether it's because the data is wrong or your XPath query
- *Consider* putting in a nullity check before accessing the value (if you should really, really always find a node, then an exception may well be the right approach already)

Comment: thanks for reply.. will try and check query line is def the Remarkict line

Answer (score 0):

Something is being used before it has been instantiated, or is otherwise `null` - is `xnMyForm` instantiated? And then further, check all other code paths to determine if elements are `null` or returning such.

Answer (score 0):

Either `xnMyForm` is `null`, or you are trying to select a node that doesn't exist in the document (using `SelectSingleNode`) and the `.Value` is invoked on the returned `null`.

Comment: thanks for the replyOded I It is a textfield in infopath which i filled in... simple text autscorrect on scroll if needed..      string RemarkIT = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:RemarksICT", ns).Value;. definitely the line returning null. dont know why though it is exately the same tekst field as teh others with the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

Very probably one of your SelectSingleNode() calls returns a null, so you cannot take  a .Value off it.

Comment: thanks for the reply Roy                                       string RemarkIT = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:RemarksICT", ns).Value;. definitely the line returning null. dont know why though it is exately the same tekst field as teh others with the same properties.

Comment: @user767533: It's not that the line is returning null - it's that the call to SelectSingleNode is returning null. You're then trying to access the Value property. My guess is that you've made a typo in the xpath epression.

Comment: Indeed... Jon expressed it better and nailed it.